Where are SQL Server Agent driver dependencies documented?
Where does Microsoft document its Driver dependencies for SQL Server Agent in SQL Server 2019? None of the following documents declare a driver version dependency:
(a) SQL Server 2019: Hardware and software requirements (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/install/hardware-and-software-requirements-for-installing-sql-server-2019
(b) Configure SQL Server Agent (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/agent/configure-sql-server-agent?view=sql-server-ver15)
(c) Microsoft ODBC Driver for SQL Server on Windows (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/windows/microsoft-odbc-driver-for-sql-server-on-windows?view=sql-server-ver15)
(d) System requirements, installation, and driver files (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/windows/system-requirements-installation-and-driver-files?view=sql-server-ver15)

What problem are you trying to solve?
